# How to initialize the `std::map<std::string, CodeInfo>` using list-initialization?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, stdmap, list-initialization

I have a map with a *string* key and a *struct* value, I don't know why I cannot instantiate an object using [a list of initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>    
using namespace std;

struct CodeInfo
{
    int _level = 0;
    bool _reactive;
};
typedef map<string, CodeInfo> CodeInfos; // Key is code name

int main()
{
    CodeInfos codes = { {"BARECODE", { 0, true }}, {"BARECODE2", { 0, false }} };

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to be straight forward but I can't understand why I get the following error:

```
In function 'int main()':    
24:80: error: could not convert '{{"BARECODE", {0, true}}, {"BARECODE2", {0, false}}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'CodeInfos {aka std::map<std::basic_string<char>, CodeInfo>}'
```

I have using compiler g++ (GCC) 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10) with C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `CodeInfo` is not aggregate, because you are initializing one of the data members(`_level = 0`) directly in the definition of the class.

Removing the [*default initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) of that member will work with C++11. [See here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ohB8Km0pxRkAFmzR)

Read this post for more information about aggregates: [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821)

Comment: "This is equivalent to providing default constructor to the class and hence will not work with list-initialization." No, not really.

Comment: And we don't usually call `int _level = 0;` "direct initialization". The standard uses the term "default member initializer".

Comment: @cpplearner Thanks for pointing out the right word. And regarding the *default constructor* , that I have found in the other answer. Could you point out me, what exactly is the difference.?